# Excel VBA - Unlock/Unhide Textbox by User Defined Amount

Tags: excel, vba

On my page in my UserForm, I need to have 1000 TextBoxes that are hidden except the first textbox. So far, this part is easy. I have added a few textboxes and created the scrollbar via page settings.

I want to unhide boxes based on what is typed in a separate textbox. Example: I type "10" and press UnHide and 10 Textboxes appear. I plan on labeling all my textboxes on this page NPTB1 - 1000. The 1000 textboxes are a place holder on my sheet for 1000 phone numbers. If a 1000 will break the form, let me know your experiences as this is my first user form digging into this amazing tool.

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Textbox1").Visible = Not ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Textbox1").Visible
```

I looked at a loop formula.

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 6
Cells(i, 1).Value = 100
Next i
```

But I keep trying to make this code work somehow replaces bits and pieces with no luck. I know this loop formula will add 1000 to 6 cells. Just not sure what I need for the userform. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with your idea of using a loop, some code like the following should suffice:

```
Dim intNumberOfTBs as Integer

'assuming you are typing in cell "A1" of "Sheet1" the number of textboxes to display
intNumberOfTBs = Sheet1.Cells(1,1).value

Dim iTB as Integer
For iTB = 1 to intNumberOfTBs
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("NPTB" & iTB).Visible = true
Next
```

You could loop through all of the oleObjects on your sheet and turn them all off first. Something like:

```
Dim oTB as Object
For each oTB in ActiveSheet.OleObjects
    If left(oTB.Name, 4) = "NPTB" Then
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("NPTB" & iTB).Visible = false
    End If
Next oTB
```

Comment: If I have a textbox on the Form for this instead of on a sheet, would I use "nameoftextbox.value" for the part after the equal sign?

Comment: something like: `intNumberOfTBs = myform.nameoftextbox.value`

Comment: I think it doesn't like this line because i'm using the VBA form instead of a sheet.    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("NPTB" & iTB).Visible = True

Answer (score 0):

Well, why are you capping it in the first place? I don't see why you would need 1000 Textboxes, since you could always collect the value from a few, save them elsewhere and then just reset.
Also, you can try adding your boxes dynamically: 
First things first, this piece of code is not in good shape:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Textbox1").Visible = Not ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Textbox1").Visible
```

You're better off setting the visible value to True or False according to what you are specifically doing at the moment.

But if you wanna unhide the textboxes programatically, and given your name reference, you'd have to go with something of the likes:

```
Dim tb as OLEObject, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
For i = 1 to numberToUnhide
    Set tb =  ws.OLEObjects("NPTB" & i)
    tb.Visible = True 
Next
```

However, I repeat, you can as well just add them during runtime. Depends on what you're planning to do with the data. Don't forget that you also need to think on the user of the worksheet, and he might just as well find it too cluttered, and simply not use it.

Best regards

Comment: I am going to test this tomorrow when I get some free time. I'll let you know how it goes. Appreciate the extra details too!

Comment: I have a form I send to businesses. It's standard form across the board. The only different is what goes in those fields. I used references on another Sheet. You know, simply Name: =Sheetname!Cell and as someone filled in the new sheet, it would auto populate those cells. Cool. But, some businesses didn't like the formulas or multiple pages that print as a result of if(cell is blank = "") so it made a lot of blanks.

Comment: TL;DR Basically, I have a form on a sheet with telephone numbers. I plan on typing the numbers into this VBA form that carries the information over to the appropriate fields instead of references. My biggest headache has been the unknown with the phone numbers. Sometimes I have 1 phone number, sometimes 10, 100, etc. So I wanted to create a way to not show all boxes. If you have a better solution to on load boxes in the NP page, I am all ears.

Comment: Is this one missing a piece for numberToUnhide? I guess I would need to define that as the textbox right?

Comment: Yes, I used the variable numberToUnhide, but you could withdraw the value from a user input.

Comment: I see. I did a userform a while ago that had an unlimited number of clickboxes, depending on the configuration for something else. It was a bit problematic at first to set things correctly (specially the formatting), but it worked after a while. But since you are collecting phone numbers, why not just use the worksheet itself?

Comment: Mainly because people are having a hard time switching between sheets. If I could create one click box form, they could key in all the information in there. I have found a way to recall old forms we sent and ways to save what is keyed into a separate file. The only trick to tying it all together is the phone numbers so it doesn't look messy. If they have to use Excel to key in phone numbers, they won't use this gadget I've created.

Comment: Have you considered using a Listbox instead of several textboxes instead? Pair ir with a button to add/remove phone button and only one textbox where people can type their phones. Something like this  http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VBImages/AddClearListBoxDelete.PNG can also work.